# Возможно ли редактировать драйвер принтера?

Tags: драйвер

Настройки принтера Samsung ML 1675 не позволяют использовать бумагу размером более чем 210X356 mm. Но специфика моей работы часто требует формата 210X500 mm. Возможно ли (и если "да", то КАК?) отредактировать драйвер? 
Если это невозможно, то подскажите, пожалуйста, марку ЛАЗЕРНОГО принтера, позволяющего печать на таком формате.

Answer (score 2):

[PostScript](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript) - ом можно. Если помню, команды кажется отличаются для каждой модели. Я писал для HP принтеров , а какие команды управляют размерами, фонтами, и тд. я взял с офф сайта HP. Предлагаю вам тоже самое, сначала посмотреть офф сайт Samsung - a.

**UPD:** хотел сказать не редактировать драйвера, о просто послать команды на печать.

**UPD:** Здесь общие положения, коды таблиц.,  и т.д можно посмотреть:

[PostScript Language Reference](http://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf)

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Завтра на работе попробую! 
(Извиняюсь за поздний ответ - уезжал...)